Kafka MirrorMaker2 cannot connect to kafka node with TLS
I have two k8s setups on which kafka clusters are running. On my origin setup no TLS or authentication is required. My target setup has both SCRAM-SHA-512 and TLS setup.
The config of my KafkaMirrorMaker2 is as follows:-
spec:
  clusters:
  - alias: source-dummy-six
    bootstrapServers: origin-kafka:9092
  - alias: target-dummy-six
    authentication:
      passwordSecret:
        password: target-password
        secretName: password-secret-dummy-six
      type: scram-sha-512
      username: kafka-username
    bootstrapServers: 10.11.12.13:32182
    config:
      config.storage.replication.factor: -1
      config.storage.topic: dummy-six-configs
      group.id: dummy-six-group-id
      offset.storage.replication.factor: -1
      offset.storage.topic: dummy-six-offset
      reconnect.backoff.max.ms: 2000
      reconnect.backoff.ms: 2000
      request.timeout.ms: 60000
      retry.backoff.max.ms: 2000
      retry.backoff.ms: 2000
      socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms: 30000
      ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm: ""
      status.storage.replication.factor: -1
      status.storage.topic: dummy-six-status
    tls:
      trustedCertificates:
      - certificate: ca.cert
        secretName: target-tls-secret-dummy-six
  connectCluster: target-dummy-six
  logging:
    loggers:
      connect.root.logger.level: INFO
    type: inline
  metricsConfig:
    type: jmxPrometheusExporter
    valueFrom:
      configMapKeyRef:
        key: mirrormaker-metrics-config
        name: mirror-maker-2-metrics
  mirrors:
  - checkpointConnector:
      config:
        checkpoints.topic.replication.factor: 1
        offset-syncs.topic.location: target
        refresh.groups.interval.seconds: 20
        replication.policy.class: com.company.CustomRepPolicy
        replication.policy.dest.metric.topic.name: test_metric_con
        sync.group.offsets.enabled: false
    groupsPattern: .*
    heartbeatConnector:
      config:
        heartbeats.topic.replication.factor: 1
    sourceCluster: source-dummy-six
    sourceConnector:
      config:
        offset-syncs.topic.location: target
        offset-syncs.topic.replication.factor: 1
        refresh.topics.interval.seconds: 20
        replication.factor: 1
        replication.policy.class: com.company.CustomRepPolicy
        replication.policy.dest.metric.topic.name: test_metric_con
        replication.policy.separator: .
        sync.group.offsets.enabled: false
        sync.topic.acls.enabled: "true"
        topic.creation.default.message.format.version: 2.8-IV0
        topic.creation.default.partitions: -1
        topic.creation.default.replication.factor: -1
      tasksMax: 4
    targetCluster: target-dummy-six
    topicsPattern: my_target_topic

This is the error I get
Node 2 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1]
2024-11-19 16:11:17,103 WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node 2 (kafka-target-cluster/10.23.52.37:32187) could not be established. Node may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1]
2024-11-19 16:11:18,769 INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node 0 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1]
2024-11-19 16:11:18,769 WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node 0 (kafka-target-cluster/10.23.52.37:32185) could not be established. Node may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1]
2024-11-19 16:11:18,770 INFO App info kafka.admin.client for adminclient-1 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser) [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1]
2024-11-19 16:11:18,771 INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Metadata update failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager) [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1]
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The AdminClient thread has exited. Call: fetchMetadata
2024-11-19 16:11:18,773 INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Timed out 1 remaining operation(s) during close. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient) [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1]
2024-11-19 16:11:18,779 INFO Metrics scheduler closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics) [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1]
2024-11-19 16:11:18,779 INFO Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics) [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1]
2024-11-19 16:11:18,779 INFO Metrics reporters closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics) [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1]
2024-11-19 16:11:18,779 ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.AbstractConnectCli) [main]
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to connect to and describe Kafka cluster. Check worker's broker connection and security properties.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConfig.lookupKafkaClusterId(WorkerConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConfig.lookupKafkaClusterId(WorkerConfig.java:285)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConfig.kafkaClusterId(WorkerConfig.java:415)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.AbstractConnectCli.startConnect(AbstractConnectCli.java:124)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.AbstractConnectCli.run(AbstractConnectCli.java:94)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:116)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listNodes
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:165)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConfig.lookupKafkaClusterId(WorkerConfig.java:299)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listNodes

What I notice is I am providing the target bootstrap-server as 10.11.12.13:32182 but it fails to reach 10.23.52.37:32185. So this means that it is able to resolve the  original bootstrap server and then identifies from the target kafka cluster metadata, the nodes. So TLS configuration and SCRAM-SHA-512 authentication is happening correctly.
Furthermore when I try to check the connection on 10.11.12.13:32182 I get this
nc -zv 10.11.12.13 32182
Ncat: Version 7.70 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 10.11.12.13:32182.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.01 seconds.

But when I do the same with 10.23.52.37:32185 I am unable to eastablish a connection
nc -zv 10.23.52.37 32185
Ncat: Version 7.70 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connection timed out.

I have also verified the tls certificate by executing this command and cross checking the ca-cert I have provided with the last certificate of the output of this command
openssl s_client -connect 10.11.12.13:32182 -showcerts

Also on my target cluster I have not defined any acls. So by default all permissions should be enabled. As determined by the output of this
 ./kafka-acls.sh    --list  --bootstrap-server 10.11.12.13:32182
Error while executing ACL command: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SecurityDisabledException: No Authorizer is configured on the broker
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SecurityDisabledException: No Authorizer is configured on the broker
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:165)
    at kafka.admin.AclCommand$AdminClientService.getAcls(AclCommand.scala:180)
    at kafka.admin.AclCommand$AdminClientService.listAcls(AclCommand.scala:149)
    at kafka.admin.AclCommand$AdminClientService.$anonfun$listAcls$1(AclCommand.scala:142)
    at kafka.admin.AclCommand$AdminClientService.listAcls(AclCommand.scala:141)
    at kafka.admin.AclCommand$.main(AclCommand.scala:77)
    at kafka.admin.AclCommand.main(AclCommand.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SecurityDisabledException: No Authorizer is configured on the broker

(I have changed the actual IP addresses)

It turned out to be a network issue. The hostname the bootstrap server was resolving to kafka-target-cluster/10.23.52.37:32185 was also present in my source k8s cluster. So it was not actually connecting to the target cluster.
